# Where can I find a Python 3-compatible library for Db2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

I have been working with Python 2 and Db2. Changing to Python 3 the same library doesn't seem to work. What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like a question for *them*, no?

Comment: I have no idea what the "real answer" is - or even if Python 3 is in fact unsupported (that surprises me).  But think about it: what would be the return on investment for creating - and supporting - a second product, vs. just one product? How many production systems (i.e. "paying customers") are actually using Python3 (to the exclusion of Python2).?  Does Python3 support make economic sense?

Comment: Because they have a different library for DB2 support: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db/

Comment: *the same library doesn't seem to work*... what does this mean? Please show attempted code and error. I recently successfully connected DB2 Express on a remote machine to Python 3.5 on client, both using Linux using [ibm_db](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html).

Answer (score 1):

[IBM provides four (4) different type of Python-related libraries for Db2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/c0054366.html):

- ibm_db
- ibm_db_dbi (DBI API)
- ibm_db_sa (SQLAlchemy)
- ibm_db_django (Django adapter)

All libraries and more information can be accessed through the documentation link. In some cases a different library is needed depending on Python 2 or 3, or on 32 bit and 64 bit systems.
In your case you probably need a newer library.